# How to put cross-referencing number in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing, tikz-arrows

I am trying to get theorem reference number generated automatically using the "`\label{thm1}`" and "`\ref{thm1}`" environment  in the following diagram. But it shows error. If I replace "`text={Theorem \ref{thm1}}`" by manually inputting the theorem number `"text={Theorem 1.1}"` in the following, it runs perfectly. How to use the command `\ref{...}` in the `decorations` environment ?

```
\documentclass[]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsxtra}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.geometric,trees}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newtheorem{Th}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{Th}
\label{thm1}
This is a theorem. 
\end{Th}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,node distance=3cm and 2.5cm]
  \node (k1) {$\underset{(1)} {Step1}$};
  \node (k2) [below=of k1] {$\underset{(2)} {Step2}$};
  \draw [->,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2ex,text along path,text align=center,text={Theorem \ref{thm1}}}}](k1) to  (k2);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless using the `calc` package, `\ref` is not an expandable command. However, `\getrefnumber` from `refcount` package is expandable, so replace `\ref` by `\getrefnumber`.

Why must it be expandable? Well, the `decoration` library needs information about the content and not only a box width and height.

I also suggest to replace `Step1` by `\text{Step 1}` etc.

```
\documentclass[]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsxtra}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.geometric,trees}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{refcount}
\newtheorem{Th}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{Th}
\label{thm1}
This is a theorem. 
\end{Th}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,node distance=3cm and 2.5cm]
  \node (k1) {$\underset{(1)} {\text{Step 1}}$};
  \node (k2) [below=of k1] {$\underset{(2)} {\text{Step 2}}$};
  \draw [->,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2ex,text align=center,text along path,text={Theorem \getrefnumber{thm1}}}}](k1) to  (k2);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How this can be modified using `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`

Comment: @user149418: I don't understand your question. The tikz `calc` library has nothing to do with your issue about the references